# Can't create log4j log file inside my web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

i am using log4j as my logging library, and i want the generated log file to be inside my web application, so following are the jars i am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and following are log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=mylog.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10000KB

log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

# Control/Limit integrated frameworks logging messages
log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR
```

**Problem**: when i use file system path like `log4j.appender.R.File=${user.home}/mylog.log` 
the file is created successfully with no problems, but when trying to use a relative path like: `log4j.appender.R.File=mylog.log` the file is not created.

please advise how to fix that.

Comment: The app probably doesn't have permission to write in the directory it's being run from.  Which is generally a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned a web application the current working directory would be the web container root -like TOMCAT_HOME. So the log file path will be relative to your web container and not your web-application.

Also most web-containers restrict writing files into the web application directories. There might be some configurations to do that - not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions of the current working directory. Be sure that user executing the Java process has read and write access.

To determine the working directory, run this from a class in the web application context (e.g. a `Servlet` or a `ServletContextListener`):

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```